# Не включается пк после перехода в спящий режим, archlinux

Tags: linux, archlinux, intel, xfce4

После перехода в спящий режим (не важно, закрыл крышку ноутбука, ввел команду `systemctl suspend` или через кнопку в GUI), пк не включается. Горит светодиод, который показывает, что пк работает, но при этом, экран полностью выключен, кулеры не работают, на нажатие клавиш не реагирует. Единственный способ снова включить, долго нажимать на кнопку выключения и заново включать. Проблема была с самого начала после установки.  драйвера обновлены (`xf86-video-intel`). 
  Дистрибутив - archlinux, DE - xfce4, ядро - x86_64 Linux 4.15.3-1-ARCH, CPU & GPU - intel, врятли на это влияет шел, но все же - zsh.

Comment: Модель ноутбука?

Comment: Acer Aspire V3-111P